# <html5> How to add mouse event drawn image in canvas

Tags: html, image, events, mouse, draw

I want to add link to image.

```
  imageObj.onload = function() {
    ctx.drawImage(imageObj, 400, 20, 365, 115);
  };
  imageObj.src = '../images/category.jpg';
```

how can I do it...

if I click image, function execute.

Answer (score 0):

You can get parent and then associate the link with it-

```
var parentEl = imageObj.parent;
var imgEl = parentEl.innerHtml;
parentEl.innerHtml = '<a href="test.html">' + imgEl + '</a>';
```

and If you want to execute a function on click of the image:
add eventlistener to it-

```
imageObj.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
 //code
  });
```

Hope, It helps!